# Mapping device hostnames to DNS automatically in DDWRT

Tags: dns, dhcp, dd-wrt, hostname

I already know how to accomplish this manually using a host file and static ip addresses

I want to map all hostnames to their IPs with a DNS entry

MY-COMPUTER -> my-computer.local -> 10.0.0.1

android-1ab2d2341deaab9e359a -> android-1ab2d2341deaab9e359a.local -> 10.0.0.172

Answer (score 0):

**You need to configure a few things**

You will need a few items in order to accomplish your goal.

1. DNS Server that you have a control over
2. Configure a forward lookup zone on the DNS server with an internal DNS domain
3. Populate your A Records in the forward lookup zone with the hostnames and IP addresses
4. Configure a forwarder on the DNS server to perform iterative requests for domains that aren't your internal DNS domain.
5. configure your workstations to use this DNS server for name resolution.  If you are using DHCP to assign IP's then you will want to assign the local domain to your internal hosts.

You should then be able to use your local DNS server for local and remote DNS based name resolution.